# "Hierarchical k-means" wrong sample assignment

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on a hierarchical k-means scheme which is translated into sequential k-means in my case.
Let say I have `10k` samples (objects to cluster) which I want to separate into 200 clusters. My approach is:

1. To split it initially into `10` clusters
2. Then split each cluster into another `5` clusters which will give me `10*5 = 50` clusters totally.
3. Finally I split each of the `50` clusters into `4` clusters and voila I have `50*4 = 200` clusters.

I am not asking for an advice of the divisive hierarchical clustering scheme, i.e. how efficient it is, how to find the number of subclusters etc.

I want to take advantage of that hierarchical splitting and use a preclustering scheme where I decide in which subcluster of the initial `10` ones the sample belongs to and then just decide in which of the `100` (`1000/10`) subclusters of this subcluster. This works faster than searching `10k` subclusters.

*The problem is* I found a subcluster (of `10k`) belonging to the final subclusters of initial 10 clusters, meaning to have smaller (not by far though) distance to another cluster.

**My question is**, whether is this possible to happen? I know that since I am using k-means all samples of each cluster have as nearest centroid the centroid of the cluster they belong to. I am using a three step clustering though that I am not sure it does not complicate things. My guess is that I have made a mistake in the code and that not possible.

A **similar question** though has risen in my mind: is it possible to find a test sample (meaning a sample that's not any of the `10k` previously mentioned ones) that it would normally be assigned to an `i` subcluster but due to my hierarchical clustering is assigned to `j`?

Edit:

I am using a k-means algorithm which means a Euclidean distance is used to create the clusters and also when deciding in which cluster a sample belongs to also an Euclidean distance is used as well.

The algorithm itself does not present any specially. It is just sequential k-means applied:

1. In step 1 in the whole training set, i.e. `10k` samples
2. In step 2 in a subset of the original set which comprise only of the samples belonging to each cluster, i.e. `100` (different) samples for each cluster
3. In the final step is applied only to the samples belonging to each of the `50` subclusters, i.e. to `200` (different) samples for each subcluster

Comment: To me, your question remains a bit complicated to grasp. You didn't expose the algorithm, nor gave a clear example. In particular, where is K-mean clustering itself - it doesn't show anywhere in the question.

Comment: k-means is not shown in the question but it is important to present it to get the idea of how the clusters are created. I would edit the question to make this clear

Comment: Just a quick fictional idea: can the _sequential_ nature of the k-means version you apply be the cause of your problem. Did you try to use standard (i.e. means update after all the objects get reassigned) k-means, to see?

Comment: I did not compare with the actual k-means algorithm since I am not interested in the best clustering performance but to a quick decent one.

Comment: Do I understand you correct? Say you split (by k-means) the whole many objects into clusters A and B. Then, likewise, you split A into A1 and A2, and B into B1 and B2. And it appeared strangely that some object of A2 is closer to the centre of B1 than it is to the own centre of A2. Is that your problem?

Comment: There are 2 questions: the first is that a sample of training set of A2 is closer to B (not B1 or B2) and the second if it's possible a test sample which normally would be assigned to A2 to be closer to B1 or B2 instead

Comment: I believe the answer to your first question is yes, it is possible. If object X of A2 is closer to centre of B than to centre of A2, then it follows that X is farther from centre of A2 than from centre of A (because distance X-A is less than X-B). It is possible, in principle: a point of a data cloud can be closer to its centre than to the centre of the subcloud (cluster) to which that point belongs.